# What would be the first thing that someone would check to resolve the UnsupportedOperationException in OC4J 10.1.3.5?

Tags: java, oc4j

What would be the first thing that someone would check to resolve the UnsupportedOperationException in OC4J 10.1.3.5? This happen during logging out.  We have two identical (from coding and classpath perspective) applications - one log out correctly, another one throws UnsupportedOperationException.

```
10/06/11 10:58:07 ERROR: Error during SSO logout
10/06/11 10:58:07 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
10/06/11 10:58:07       at oracle.adf.share.DefaultContext.loadEnvironment(ADFContext.java:574)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at oracle.adf.share.ADFContext.getEnvironment(ADFContext.java:365)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at oracle.adf.share.http.HttpSessionScopeAdapter.getSession(HttpSessionScopeAdapter.java:318)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at oracle.adf.share.http.HttpSessionScopeAdapter.invalidate(HttpSessionScopeAdapter.java:524)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at oracle.adf.share.http.HttpSessionScopeAdapter.valueUnbound(HttpSessionScopeAdapter.java:584)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpSession.destroy(EvermindHttpSession.java:472)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.invalidateSession(HttpApplication.java:1007)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.invalidateSession(HttpApplication.java:978)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpSession.invalidate(EvermindHttpSession.java:411)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpSession.invalidate(EvermindHttpSession.java:378)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.polk.connect.view.util.SSOUtils.doSSOLogout(SSOUtils.java:222)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.polk.connect.view.security.AuthServlet.execute(AuthServlet.java:127)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.polk.connect.view.security.AuthServlet.doGet(AuthServlet.java:68)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:734)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:313)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:199)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
10/06/11 10:58:07       at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` are thrown by a library if.. .well some operation is not supported.

This is totally optional and should be documented in the API.

This is common for instance in JDBC drivers where even for the same DB one driver may throw it and other no ( use to happen to me with Oracle driver and weblogic internal driver )

So, the first thing you have to take a look at is the library documentation and see what's the alternative.

**edit**

BTW the second thing you have to do is create a service request in metalink ( or whatever is that called now )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The Metalink Note

UnsupportedOperationException When Invalidating ADF Session After Upgrading to 10.1.3.5 [ID 974429.1] tells that patch 9077465 contains a fix for this bug.